# Is it ok to create tags for specific markets?

Tags: support, tags

I'm very interested in marriage and dating, and how people match. Can I create a marriage-market tag?

Or if someone is really interested in oil prices, is it good to create a oil-market tag?

But maybe too few people are interested in the oil market, or the marriage market, and a broader tag like non-renewable-resource-market or one-to-one-matching-market would be (better?) the type of tag to create.

So what I want to know is this:

1. Are tags for markets generally a good/bad idea?
2. If they are good, how specific/broad should the market be?

Comment: On a related note, is your [question](http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/11482/causes-of-upward-trend-in-median-first-marriage-age-in-usa) about economics? I don't mind the question at all, but I would think this is more in the realm of sociology.

Comment: @denesp You're right, it's more in the realm of sociology. But also, yeah, it's about economics, no question. It has a lot to do with economic theories about matching. It can totally be studied in behavioral economics. Also, it's especially relevant in labor economics. Marital status has a lot to do with income. It has to do with children's outcomes in school and criminal activity and therefore the labor market. Economics is a social science. Yeah my question is probably more relevant to and more studied in sociology, but the two fields overlap. I'm more interested in the economics side of it.

Comment: Or, I'm the most interested in what economics can say about it.

Comment: @ColeTrumbo well, most of the text of that marriage question refers explicitly to the non-economic aspects. Please edit the question to remove all of that, and be explicit that you are only interested in the economic aspect of the question.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers do you not think the two overlap? Tell me what to remove and I'll consider it. But it's pretty freaking obvious I'm looking for an economics answer. This is Economics SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do have the [energy](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy) tag, which might give you an idea of the scope of such sectoral tags - the energy sector is a few percent of global gdp, there is a specific research discipline of energy economics, and there are quite a few people out there who describe themselves as energy economists. If a sector is huge, with some sector-specific economic theory and application, then it probably deserves its own tag.

Whereas an [oil-market](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil-market) tag, at this point in the site's life would be far too specific. And as for [marriage-market](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage-market), as the only question I've seen here to date is at time of writing a sociology question not an economics question, and as it's not a huge part of global GDP, then it seems to be to be far too specific. If you're interested in [behavioral-economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavioral-economics), then just use that tag.

Comment: What? "Not an economics question"? Where do you guys get off?

Comment: Also, solid answer. Thanks, the tagging makes sense now.